# Anonymous function signature in typescript type. What does this mean?

Tags: typescript

I know how to define a type in TypeScript that expects a named function like this:

```js
type Foo = {
    bar(a: string): number
}

// or

type Foo = {
    bar: (a:string) => number
}
```

However, with the first approach it's also possible to define a function without a name like this:

```js
type Foo = {
    (a: string): number
}
```

The TypeScript compiler doesn't complain here but I have no idea how you would create an object matching this type signature? Trying something like this does not compile:

```js
let f: Foo = {
  (a: string) => 2
}
```

So the question is: What does the above type definition actually means? Is it possible to create an object matching this signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an alternative way to write:

```
type Foo = (a: string) => number;
```

...but you can also include other properties the function would have, for instance:

```
type Foo = {
    (a: string): number;
    b: boolean;
};
```

...defines a type for a function that accepts a string, returns a number, and has a `b` property (on the function) that's a boolean.

[Fun on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=32#code/PTAEE0HsFcCdQC4E8AOBTAUM9oBilJQBeUAbw1FAAoBDALlAGcFYBLAOwHMBKB96ALYAjNLADcGAL4SMIUAFEAjtFYA3GgBs07BIlSZsaUACEa8ErQbM2XbsQB8ofsNEy5ABViRVHTogAWaEgA5LBGaMpqmtq6VJDwNLpaNMygAMaQAiiJrEJa3BgZ7Kn0eATE1KXWvnZEjgAsAEwSRalCDKbmoDRioHIAPEQkAOrxANaMGLJgAJLsaRrQACa+3aAoXuiwyKCQ7AFGAGbQ8wise1j6ZZCNFeSUlkwsNXyCIuIUoO1fBMnsEtIpnIAMJhHJcXbsTCtXQADwAjBVHtVbK8XOYGs0MFpdId4Qx8DcKgjegMhgpYF54CI0jRoIwjAADBGM0BLSBoRjsYK6fw0VRMoSMqYw0Cw24WKrPVFON6iBygJoScUAOiEFRY0DQEhxoEOjQJBAlYuafTAgxG40YQA):

```
// Your type
type Foo = {
  (a: string): number;
};

// Equivalent type
type Bar = (a: string) => number;

// Proving they're equivalent (or at least compatible)
const a: Foo = (a: string) => 42;
const b: Bar = a; // <== Works

// Including a property on the function
type Foo2 = {
  (a: string): number;
  b: boolean;
};

// Creating one
const x1 = (a: string): number => 42;
let f1: Foo2 = x1; // <== Error because `x1` doesn't have `b`

const x2 = (a: string): number => 42;
x2.b = true;
let f2: Foo2 = x2; // <== Works
```

Comment: I'd normally cite documentation, but...I can't find it in the documentation. :-) I figured it out by playing on the playground.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but now I have a follow-up question: It's also possible to have multiple anonymous function signatures in a Type like this:


type Foo = {
 (a: string): number,
 (a: number): string
}

Is this some kind of overloading then?

Comment: @ManuelMauky - [Looks that way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEE0HsFcCdQC4E8AOBTAUM9oBilJQBeUAbw1FAAoBDALlAGcFYBLAOwHMBKB96ALYAjNLADcFavSYsOnADSghDZmy69Q-YaIkBfCRgDGkds1AAzBvkIlaK2V0VCA-PbU8+gkfCIA+UAAsAEwSxqaQADZoAHQRkJxU5lQARCZoydzcoSaMkTFxCUmp7OmKyQgA7pAZWUA), yeah. :-)

Comment: This is really interesting. But it only works when the return type is the same. If the return type is different it stops working: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEHcHsCcGsGcBQAXAngBwKagGKUqALygDeiooAFAIYBco8y0AlgHYDmAlPawK4C2AI0zQA3OSp1QfISO7SBwsYgC+4xAGNIrRqABm9PAWI16jFh1AAfAAUyl8+yKIA+UABYATOsQhQAE0hMeGlIZAgYWBQMbAAhamgiUglTBiY2Lh5FEXEKSkEs2Wh5cwzxFURNbV12enjEkylSjhsrBSLHbMTbZvZXD08gA)

Comment: @ManuelMauky - That's interesting... You can do that with normal function overloading. Huh.